# Is there any mathematical trick?

Tags: algorithms, recreational-mathematics

Given two natural numbers I am supposed to reverse each of them and then sum them up and reverse the sum to get the final answer.

For example if the numbers are $4358$ and $754$ then the answer should be $1998$

I always thought that there should be a mathematical trick avoid brute force (i.e reversing each numbers and summing them up and reverse the sum to get the final answer).I heard "**double reverse is no reverse**" but never really get the trick myself.Could anybody help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Line the numbers up flush left. When you carry a digit, carry to the right. Something like

```
4358
754  (+
------
11
 8
  9
   8
------
1998
```

Comment: So it's boils down to the simple addition routine without reversing the strings first ... Thanks :-)